# Serial Port Issue

Tags: reset, serial

I am a new linux user, I have a workstation connected to a testing device through serial port (ttyS0) then suddenly it stopped working.
I connected USB-Serial adapter to check the software also was good.
I cannot use USB-Serial adaptor to my device because some functions won't work with it.
Used ttyS1 in the instead of ttyS0 also didn't work for me
I need your help to fix this issue
I had screenshots form device manager and terminal might help to solve the issue
If there is any way to check that the serial port is working or not? or there is any way to reset the serial configuration?

[image]

Comment: I assume this is a 9 or 25 pin serial port. Could you fashion a null-modem with a piece of wire and a plug? Just connect RX to TX and see if you can echo what you send. If that doesn't work, then it could be an issue with the UART chip on the motherboard or the UART driver.

Comment: Its 9- pin serial port.
You mean join pin 2 & 3 togeter, right?
Then how to echo. What is the command?

Comment: Yes, 2 & 3. You need an equivalent program to Hyperterminal.

Comment: *"suddenly it stopped working"* -- That is a conclusion rather than a useful description of the problem or symptoms that you actually observed.  The file to check for the status of serial terminals is `/proc/tty/driver/serial` (or other files in `/proc/tty/driver/`). What @spikey_richie called a *"null-modem"* is actually a *loopback test*, and you could use a terminal emulation program such as **minicom**.

Comment: @sawdust yes, you're right. I meant a loopback test.